# Trouble converting data.frame to eventlog in bupaR (R package)

Tags: r, dataframe, converters

I'm attempting to use the bupaR package (an R package).

I'm having some difficulty creating an eventlog from a data.frame. I get the same error message when I try to create an eventlog using my own data, and when I try to create an eventlog as per the example code on the R Documentation page:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bupaR/versions/0.3.2/topics/eventlog

Example code from the site copied here:

```
data <- data.frame(case = rep("A",5),
activity_id = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
activity_instance_id = 1:5,
lifecycle_id = rep("complete",5),
timestamp = 1:5,
resource = rep("resource 1", 5))

eventlog(data,case_id = "case",
activity_id = "activity_id",
activity_instance_id = "activity_instance_id",
lifecycle_id = "lifecycle_id",
timestamp = "timestamp",
resource_id = "resource")
```

The error message is: 
Error in .f(.l[[c(1L, i)]], .l[[c(2L, i)]], ...) : 
  ..2 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in

Is there some sort of problem in the way I'm initialising the variables, or calling them in the eventlog function? I've tried making lifecycle_id and activity_instance_id factors, and explicitly making the timestamp column a Date or a POSIXct type, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating the package using:

```
devtools::install_github("gertjanssenswillen/bupaR", ref = "eventlog-ordering")
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

This turned out to be an issue with the firewalls within the system I was using. Manually uninstalling and reinstalling bupaR and specifying package location when reinstalling fixed the issue.

Specifying package location at the install step is essential for anyone working on a restricted system! :)